# how to find xmlns definition?

Tags: html, blogger, xml-namespaces

I see

```
 xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' 
 xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data'
 xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'
```

`xmlns` definition in Blogger template,but I can not find the full description about `b` data or `exp`r, so where to find these `xmlns` concrete description?

Answer (score 2):

A tad late, but hope this helps someone else looking for the same answer.

These are xml name space definitions - as you rightly pointed out. The destination does not need to exist in reality. The URI path just helps ensure that it is unique. [Details on w3schools.blog](https://www.w3schools.blog/xml-namespaces)

The URIs in the following code do not exist as locations that can be visited but only as references:

```
 xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' 
 xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data'
 xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'
```

PS: I understand that the underlying purpose of your question is to answer 'How can we access the Blogger XML schema?' Please post this as a separate question so that relevant experts can guide.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

`b` stands for `Blog`

`data` stands for `param`

`expr` stands for `Holycow`

Comment: I mean where to find  http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr, there must be a define xml file.

Comment: google.com/2005/gml/expr [not found](https://validator.w3.org/checklink?uri=google.com%2F2005%2Fgml%2Fexpr&hide_type=all&depth=&check=Check). As are the others.